# Update a record in one table (gridview) and add it in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So what I mean is... Lets say we have this table named "Matched_table":

```
Date          Game   Client        cost
12-12-2001    Game1  Jonh          200
12-12-2003    Game2  Jonathan      100
```

Now we have another table named "NonMatched_table", this table is for the records that don't have records that match with "costumer name", also this table lets the user update the Costumer name column to make the record a "match record":

```
   Date      Game      Costumer name     cost
12-05-2001   Game1       Empty           200 
12-05-2001   Game1       Empty           200
12-05-2001   Game1       Empty           200
12-05-2001   Game1       Carl           200   <--- Updated Record:
```

When Updated this should happen:

----   "Matched_ table"----

```
   Date          Game   Client        cost
   12-12-2001    Game1  Jonh          200
   12-12-2003    Game2  Jonathan      100
   12-05-2001    Game1  Carl          200
```

----   "NonMatched_table"    ---

```
Date      Game        Costumer name     cost
12-05-2001   Game1       Empty           200 
12-05-2001   Game1       Empty           200
12-05-2001   Game1       Empty           200
```

Doesn't exist a query that does that or something? I'm doing in c# this query `string query = "UPDATE NonMatched_table SET costumer= @costumer where ID = @Id Insert into Matched_table";` I'm Wondering if I could do like an `Insert into` after or before and a delete too to erase the record

Comment: You can do multiple update delete and insert by encompassing them in a stored procedure.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm a beginner in asp.net you think that is the easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have very specific reasons to do that you can follow a much simpler approach:

- Have all records in one table, e.g. `MyTable` with columns `Date`, `Game`, `Client`, `Cost`.
- Simply use `SELECT` to filter the table. For unmatched records the query is:

  `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Client IS NULL`

  For matched records the query is:

  `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Client IS NOT NULL`
- Alternatively, you can use the above queries to create two views of `MyTable` one for matched and one for unmatched records.

Your approach while possible will raise data integrity issues sooner or later, I am afraid.

**UPDATE**

Just for the fun of it here's a working sample of what I suggest:

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource 
                ID="SqlDataSourceUnmatched" 
                runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Date], [Game], [Client], [Cost] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ([Client] IS NULL)"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [MyTable] SET [Date]=@Date, [Game]=@Game, [Client]=@Client, [Cost]=@Cost WHERE [Id]=@Id"
                OnUpdating="SqlDataSourceUnmatched_Updating">
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32"/>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Game" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Client" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Cost" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView 
                ID="GridViewUnmatched" 
                runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceUnmatched"
                OnRowUpdated="GridViewUnmatched_RowUpdated">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Id" 
                        HeaderText="Id"  />
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Date" 
                        HeaderText="Date"  />
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Game" 
                        HeaderText="Game" />
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Client" 
                        HeaderText="Customer Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Cost" 
                        HeaderText="Cost" />
                    <asp:CommandField 
                        ButtonType="Link" 
                        ShowEditButton="true"
                        ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource 
                ID="SqlDataSourceMatched" 
                runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Date], [Game], [Client], [Cost] FROM [MyTable] WHERE ([Client] IS NOT NULL)">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView 
                ID="GridViewMatched" 
                runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMatched">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Date" 
                        HeaderText="Date"/>
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Game" 
                        HeaderText="Game" />
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Client" 
                        HeaderText="Client" />
                    <asp:BoundField 
                        DataField="Cost" 
                        HeaderText="Cost" />
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No matched records.
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void GridViewUnmatched_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewMatched.DataBind();
    }

    protected void SqlDataSourceUnmatched_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {            
        // assert the record update
        e.Command.Parameters["@Date"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the target framework is .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I said, or I didn't made clear... I already have the tables with the "match" and "unmatched" values, what I want is to be able to do an update in non-match table (column: costumer name) and when I save the value, the full record saves in the Matched_table

Comment: @PuppyPoop Your question was clear. What I suggest is you don't need multiple tables. You can have both matches and unmatched values in one table. Think about it.

Comment: I know I can, but I don't it to cause like that the user can edit the matched values too, so it's better to have a table with the unmatched values when the user can edit it and other to see the values that are already matched...

Comment: @PuppyPoop I see. I rest my case since I cannot help you further with an approach that's based on bad database design. I can only say that you need all three steps (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) to be executed in one atomic operation so as to maintain data integrity. One solution is to bundle all three in a stored procedure and execute that stored procedure in your code. Please note, that this is not a asp.net issue; it is a database issue. Also note that executing 3 distinct queries in your code one after the other to update and move the record from one table to the other is a **bad** idea.

Comment: Maybe if I do a button that converts all records with the `Costumer name not null` and insert on the matched_Table after update it will work

Comment: @PuppyPoop Just for completeness and fun I've updated my answer to include a working sample.

Comment: Should I replace the `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ` with what?

Comment: Maybe with mine connectionString right? anyway its always giving me an error, `near nvarchar`